# svnserve: can I have common configuration for all my repos

Tags: svn, repository, svnserve

I am trying to have a local repository for my personal projects. With one or two users. And as many projects as I wish. Mainly in a shared MyBookLive disks. svn server is running in a local mac mini pointing to that shared disk.

I found every svn repo have its own `svnserve.conf` file.

Is it possible to use a common `svnserve.conf` file for all my projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnserve.html) (v1.7) does not seem to have any option to override the file name of `svnserve.conf`, so I would suggest either:

1. Keep all your projects together in one repository, and give each one a top-level folder, with `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches` under each.
2. Store `svnserve.conf` in one common location, and use symbolic links in each of the other repositories, so that they all share the same actual file.

Answer (score 2):

Each repo does have its own `svnserve.conf`, but this can be overridden in 1.8 with the  `--config-file` parameter.

You can have a `svnserve` process access all of your repos by giving it the parent directory that services all or your repositories.

In fact, you can even use LDAP for read/commit permissions in `svnserve` using [SASL](http://ximalas.info/2014/01/10/ldap-authentication-for-subversions-svnserve-on-freebsd-using-sasl-saslauthd-and-novell-edirectory/)

It might be worth looking into using `svnserve` instead of httpd. It seems like anything you can do with httpd can be done with svnserve now.

Comment: --config-file, thats something I am looking for. Unfortunately, my default svn version in mac is 1.7

Comment: I've installed 1.8 on my Mac. You can get the 1.8 Mac version from [Wandisco](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download). It installs in /opt/subversion. I link all of the executables under `/opt/subversion/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`which I include in my `$PATH` before `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. This way I can override the default installed versions of files. I have a more modern version of `git` and `vim` installed than what comes on the Mac by default too.